# No se carga el main de una clase en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

He creado el siguiente código en eclipse y al ejecutar me da el error

> Could not find or load main class

Todos los imports se realizaron sin dificultad.
La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:
Soy nuevo programando en Java y la verdad que ya se me quemaron los libros. El código es más extenso, pero la estructura es como se las paso a continuación.
Cualquier sugerencia será bienvenida.
Muchas gracias!!

```
package JavaPoi;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.*;

public class JavaPoiUtils {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        UtilidadJavaPoi javaPoiUtils=new UtilidadJavaPoi();
        javaPoiUtils.readExcelFile(new File("C:/productos2.xls"));
        
    }
}

class UtilidadJavaPoi {
    
    public void readExcelFile(File excelFile){
          
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿En la configuración de ejecución de Eclipse has especificado qué clase es la que contiene el main que quieres arrancar?

Answer (score 0):

Desde el explorador de archivos que tiene Eclipse, click derecho sobre la clase que quieras ejecutar y veras una opción llamada "Run as", al desplegarla veras la opción que dice "Java Application", de esa forma debería ejecutare el main de esa clase.

Como ultimo recurso, otra opción que me funciono fue crear otro proyecto java, crear las mismas clases y copiar el código de un sitio a otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias Javiluli.dev. Probé con tu sujerencia de "Run as" y no anduvo. Creo que voy a seguir con tu segunda recomendación de crear un nuevo proyecto.

Comment: Hice otra clase y al final no anduvo.